# How to compute and evaluate composite function in GP?

Tags: pari-gp

I found a workaround to make composite function, but I believe there should be a better way to do this:

```
? f = x^2
%1 = x^2
? g = x^3      
%2 = x^3
? x = g
%3 = x^3
? fog = eval(f) 
%4 = x^6
? x = 2
%5 = 2
? result = eval(fog)
%6 = 64
```

In this method, I need to assign `x` many times and I don't want to use `eval` function. The code is not readable and maintainable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PARI/GP supports the anonymous closures. So you can define the function composition on your own like this:

```
comp(f: t_FUNC, g: t_FUNC) = {
    h = (x) -> f(g(x))
};
```

Then your code can be transformed to a more readable form:

```
f(x) = x^2;
g(x) = x^3;

h = comp(f, g);
h(x)
? x^6

x = 2; h(x)
? 64
```

Hope, this helps.

Comment: Many thanks for reply. As a note, I couldn't print h(x) as (x^6) again after this line(x = 2; h(x)). If I change variable name x to y (y = 2; h(y) print(h(y)); print(h(x));) or not use variable name (print(h(2)); print(h(x))) while evaluation, then I can see (x^6) again

Comment: To clear the `x` variable you can use the built-in function `kill`. For example, `x = 2; print(h(x)); kill(x); h(x)` will print `64` and `x^6` as expected.

Answer (score 4):

1. You can simplify Piotr's nice answer to

   ```
   comp(f, g) = x->f(g(x));
   ```

Indeed, you do not need to assign to the (global) variable `h` in the `comp` function itself. Also, the braces are not necessary for a single-line statement, and neither are type annotations (which are meant to optimize the byte compiler output or help `gp2c`; in this specific case they do not help).
Finally the parentheses around the argument list are optional in the closure definition when there is a single argument, as `(x)` here.

2. I would modify the examples as follows

   ```
   f(x) = x^2;
   g(x) = x^3;
   h = comp(f, g);

   ? h('x)     \\ note the backquote
   %1 = x^6
   ? h(2)
   %2 = 64
   ```

The backquote in `'x` makes sure we use the *formal* variable `x` and not whatever value was assigned to the GP variable with that name. For the second example, there is no need to assign the value `2` to `x`, we can call `h(2)` directly

P.S. The confusion between formal variables and GP variables is unfortunate but very common for short names such as `x` or `y`. The quote operator was introduced to avoid having to `kill` variables. In more complicated functions, it can be cumbersome to systematically type `'x` instead of `x`. The idiomatic construct to avoid this is `my(x = 'x)`. This makes sure that the `x` GP variable really refers to the formal variable in the current scope.